# How to set focus on textbox on texbox_exit event

Tags: vba, excel

On a userform, I have 4 columns x 10 lines of textboxes. When the first character in the second textbox is in the row "%", I need to set the focus on the 2nd textbox in the next line, otherwise I need to focus on the next textbox (third on the same line).

Here is my code:

```
Const ST_VPISOV = 4
Public Set_fokus As Boolean

Private Sub tb1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  Vnos Me.tb1
End Sub

Private Sub tb2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  Vnos Me.tb2
End Sub
```

...

```
Private Sub tb40_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  Vnos Me.tb40
End Sub


Sub Vnos(tb As Object)

  Dim Vpis As String

  If Set_fokus Then Exit Sub

  stKrog = Me.MultiPage1.value
  Vpis = tb.Text

  If tb.Text = "" Then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  tb_column = CInt(Mid(tb.Name, 3)) Mod ST_VPISOV
  If tb_column = 0 Then tb_column = ST_VPISOV


  If tb_column = 2 Then
    If Left(Vpis, 1) = "%" Then  ' Set focus on 2nd textbox in next row
      Set_fokus = True
      Me.MultiPage1.Pages(stKrog).Controls("tb" & CInt(Mid(tb.Name, 3)) + 4).SetFocus
    Else                          ' set focus on 3rd (next) textbox in same row
      Set_fokus = True
      Me.MultiPage1.Pages(stKrog).Controls("tb" & CInt(Mid(tb.Name, 3)) + 1).SetFocus
    End If
  ElseIf tb_column = 4 Then       ' set focus on 4th textbox in next row
      Set_fokus = True
      Me.MultiPage1.Pages(stKrog).Controls("tb" & CInt(Mid(tb.Name, 3)) + 5).SetFocus
  End If

  Debug.Print Me.MultiPage1.Pages(stKrog).ActiveControl.Name

  Set_fokus = False

End Sub
```

When I run this code and put value like "%12345" in tb2 and I press Enter, focus actually go on tb6, but then jumps to tb7 and finish in tb5.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

[Picture of userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4zbf.jpg)

I tried as @AcsEmo suggest:

```
Sub Vnos(tb As Object)

  Dim Vpis As String

  stKrog = Me.MultiPage1.value
  Vpis = tb.Text

  If tb.Text = "" Or Izhod Then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  tb_column = CInt(Mid(tb.Name, 3)) Mod ST_VPISOV
  If tb_column = 0 Then tb_column = ST_VPISOV

  Debug.Print "1st debug in Vnos: " & Me.MultiPage1.Pages(stKrog).ActiveControl.Name

  itb = CInt(Mid(tb.Name, 3))
  If itb >= 40 Then itb = 0
  With Me.MultiPage1.Pages(stKrog)
        If tb_column = 2 And Left(Vpis, 1) = "%" Or tb_column = 4 Then  ' Set focus on 2nd textbox in next row
             .Controls("tb" & itb + 4).SetFocus
        Else                ' set focus on next textbox
             .Controls("tb" & itb + 1).SetFocus
        End If
  End With

  Debug.Print "2nd debug in Vnos: " & Me.MultiPage1.Pages(stKrog).ActiveControl.Name

End Sub
```

Now goes focus from tb2 to tb6 end ended in tb4.
I also add textbox_enter events for all textboxs:

```
Private Sub tb1_Enter()
Debug.Print "Enter: " & Me.MultiPage1.Pages(stKrog).ActiveControl.Name
End Sub
```

Here is picture of what I get:
[Debugging 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXQxa.jpg)

Comment: After pressing `Enter`, the focus is on `tb5` and the debug.print shows `tb6`, `tb7`, and `tb5`?

Comment: Yes. After pressing `Enter` in tb2 the debug.print shows tb6, tb7, and tb5

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine if tb2 begins with %. Then it's OK when tb6 doesn't begin with %. The code doesn't process tb7 (you only check column 2 and 4), so jumping from tb7 to tb5 may be due to tab order. So I'd refactor your code a bit like this (assuming that pressing Enter in column 4 should always move the focus to next row in column 4, otherwise the focus should jump to next textbox):

```
iTB = CInt(Mid(tb.Name, 3))
if iTB >= 40 Then iTB = 0
With Me.MultiPage1.Pages(stKrog)
      If tb_column = 2 And Left(Vpis, 1) = "%" or tb_column = 4 Then  ' Set focus on 2nd textbox in next row
           .Controls("tb" & iTB + 4).SetFocus
      Else                ' set focus on next textbox 
           .Controls("tb" & iTB + 1).SetFocus
      End If
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I change `.Controls("tb" & iTB + 4).SetFocus` with `.tb15.SetFocus` but when I press Enter in tb2, focus in set on tb4. Focus goes from tb2 to tb15 and then in tb4. I really don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code from:

```
Private Sub tb1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  Vnos Me.tb1
End Sub
```

to:

```
Private Sub tb2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  Vnos Me.tb2
  Cancel = CancelFokus
  CancelFokus = False
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub tb2_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
      If KeyCode = 13 Then
        NastaviFokus Me.tb2
      End If
End Sub

Sub NastaviFokus(tb As Object)
Dim stVnosGosta As Integer, StGost As Integer
Dim Vpis As String, ImeGosta As String
Dim PrestaviFokus As Integer

CancelFokus = False

If tb.Text = "" Or Izhod Then
  Exit Sub
End If

Vpis = tb.Text
PrestaviFokus = 0

StGost = Int(Split(Gost_Krog2(tb.Name, ST_VPISOV), ";")(0))
stVnosGosta = Int(Split(Gost_Krog2(tb.Name, ST_VPISOV), ";")(1))

With Worksheets(VP_LIST)

  If stVnosGosta = 2 Then
    If Left(Vpis, 1) = "%" Then
      Vpis = DobiVpis(Vpis)
      tb.Text = Vpis
      If Len(Vpis) > 2 Then

        If Len(ImeGosta) > 2 Then
          Controls("tb" & CInt(Mid(tb.Name, 3)) + 1).Text = ImeGosta
          .Cells(StGost + 1, 3).Value2 = ImeGosta
          .Cells(StGost + 1, stVnosGosta).Value2 = Vpis
          .Cells(StGost + 1, 5).Value2 = Me.MultiPage1.value + 1
          PrestaviFokus = 4
        End If
      Else
        CancelFokus = True
      End If
    End If
  ElseIf stVnosGosta = 4 And IsNumeric(Vpis) Then
    PrestaviFokus = 4
  End If
End With

'        Me.MultiPage1.Pages(stKrog).Controls("tb" & CInt(Mid(tb.Name, 3)) + 8).SetFocus

If Not PrestaviFokus = 0 And _
    (PrestaviFokus + (CInt(Mid(tb.Name, 3)) - 1)) \ 40 = Me.MultiPage1.value Then
  Me.Controls("tb" & CInt(Mid(tb.Name, 3)) + PrestaviFokus).SetFocus
End If

End Sub
```

and now .SetFocus works just like I want.

I guess VBA excel can't set focus on textbox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean) event, and you must use textbox_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer) event.

Thank you all for your help.

Best regards,
Matjaž